# Scrape BSCScan Token Holdings Page

Tags: web-scraping, binance, python-requests-html, bscscan

I'm trying to get data from this page

```
https://bscscan.com/tokenholdings?a=0xFAe2dac0686f0e543704345aEBBe0AEcab4EDA3d
```

But the Website owner doesn't provide endpoints APIs for this purpose. So I tried to achieve it in different ways:

-USING DRYSCRAPE but the library seems to be abandoned;

-USING REQUESTS but the data are provided dinamically by javascript;

-USING REQUESTS HTML but even in this case the data doesn't seems to be loaded.

I would like to ignore selenium cause it's slow but I don't know how to solve this issue. Anyone has a solution that could work? The data I need is the table containing the tokens of the wallet. Thank U in advice and hv a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with requests-html, for example let's grab the symbol of the first row:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

url='https://bscscan.com/tokenholdings'
token={'a': '0xFAe2dac0686f0e543704345aEBBe0AEcab4EDA3d'}

r = session.get(url, params=token)
r.html.render(sleep=2)

binance_row = r.html.find('tbody tr', first=True)
symbol = binance_row.find('td')[2].text

print(symbol)
```

Output:

```py
BNB
```

Comment: It is great, could you please show how I could fetch all elements on the table row by row? Thank you.